# Display list of lists using mvxlistview

Tags: android, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I want to display a list of lists My data is an ObservableCollection where the SomeClass has another ObservableCollection in it.

Here is the code:
This is the main list:

```
<Mvx.MvxListView
        android:id="@+id/MenuList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Path=Dishes"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/menuitemtemplate"            
        android:background="@color/backgroundlightgray"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Here is the item template which has another list inside it

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/Com.TasteITAndroidClient"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
<TextView
    android:text="Text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ff000000"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:padding="10dp" />
<Mvx.MvxListView
    android:id="@+id/CategoryDishes"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Path=Items"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/userpagedishtemplate"
    style="@style/ToolBarImage"
    android:background="@color/backgroundlightgray"       
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
```

The userpagedishtemplate displays the item.

Basically it works but I am getting very small sized lists which show 1-2 items although I specified height=wrap_content on the subList.

Have I missed something? should I be doing something else?

Thanks

Amit

Comment: I think you should use native ExpandableListView..look at this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Placing a ListView that scrolls vertically inside another ListView which scrolls vertically is likely to cause touch area confusion for your users - which list scrolls...

If you really want a list within a list then you cab use the layout you've started on - but you will probably need to give the inner lists some assistance with their vertical sizing - something more than `wrap_content`

Alternatively, for very small inner lists, you could consider switching to MvxLinearLayout.

Alternatively, you could consider making the inner lists scroll horizontally.

Alternatively, you could consider collapsing your lists into a single list using a polymorphic-aware adapter to determine whether to show a  header cell or an inner cell.